# Ephemeral port detection

Tags: networking, port, packet-injection

I'm currently studing how OS assign ephemeral ports. 

I know that years ago on application's requests, the OS used to open ephemeral ports progressively, but now due to a too easy detection for packet injection it has changed.

My question is, how the OS is currently choosing which ephemeral port to open?
Is it still possibile a packet injection without brute forcing all the possible ports? (if yes, how?)

Thanks

Comment: "_how the OS is currently choosing which ephemeral port to open?_" Different OSes do it differently, and, in fact, each could have a different port range for ephemeral ports.

Comment: Do you know in which file I can find that particular procedure in the Linux kernel?